# Refresh iPhone simulator with hardware keyboard disconnected

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

i'm testing a react-native iphone app on the xcode iphone simulator.  i don't think this is a react-native specific problem, but included that info in case it's relevant.

i'm trying to create a page that autofocuses a `TextInput` when it loads, with the keyboard visible.  Now, in order to get the simulator to auto-show the keyboard when a text input gains focus, I have to disonnect the hardware keyboard.

the catch is that with the hardware keyboard disconnected, i can no longer `Cmd+R` to refresh the app, which I have to do manually whenever I have an error.

is there some other way to refresh the simulator when the hardware keyboard is disconnected?

Comment: Hi @Jonah you can actually toggle the software keyboard once and for all (I edited my answer). Keep your hardware keyboard connected, toggle the software keyboard and then you can cmd+R as much as you want, the soft keyboard will show up on autoFocus

Answer (score 1):

1. First right click your **Simulator**
2. Then Press **Hardware**
3. Press **Shake Gesture**
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cHHA.png)
4. finally **disable Live Reload**
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOhpO.png)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the simulator to auto-show the keyboard when a text input gains focus, I just use the emulator option `Hardware > Keyboard > Toggle Software Keyboard`.

I only toggle it once and keep the hardware keyboard connected, which allows me to do `cmd + r` and have the best of both worlds.

I can `cmd+r` as much as I want and the soft keyboard will still show up.

[image]

Comment: thanks, but I specifically need to test the keyboard appearing when the form is auto-focused.  Manually `Cmd+K`-ing myself won't do that...

Comment: @Jonah you can toggle it once and for all.
Keep your hardware keyboard connected, toggle the software keyboard and then you can cmd+R as much as you want, the soft keyboard will show up on autoFocus

Answer (score 0):

You can enabled live reload from the debug menu which causes the application to reload every time you make changes to the javascript.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html

Comment: Sometimes this stops working, and requires a `Cmd-R` refresh, after you get an error.